# 2 dimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

we have these arrays....

```
$cities = array("nagpur","kanpur","delhi","chd","Noida","mumbai","nagpur");
$names = array("munish","imteyaz","ram","shyam","ankit","Rahul","mohan");
```

now i want a 2 dimensional array with name of city as key and all the corresponding names as its values.

```
<?php
$cities = array("nagpur","kanpur","nagpur","delhi","kanpur");
$names = array("ankit","atul","aman","amit","manu");
foreach ($cities as $i => $value) {
 echo "\n";

 echo $value;
 $city=$value;
 $k=0;
 foreach ($cities as $ii => $m) {
  If($city==$m)
 {
  echo$names[$ii] ;
  $final[$i][$k]=$names[$ii];


  $arr = array($city => array($k =>$names[$ii] ));
   $k++;
 }

 }
 echo"\n<tr></tr>";
}
```

wat i tried is this.but it doesnt work.help me

Comment: How do you know which names belong to a city? Can you give an example of how the resulting array should look like? You can use array_combine as Johannes proposes but this would create a one dimensional array, so I am unsure what you want...

Comment: like for nagpur the values will be munish and mohan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't expect PHP to guess how to pair those, now can you?

What you actually want to do is:

```
$final=array(
    "nagpur" => array("munish","imteyaz"),
    "kanpur" => array("ram","shyam"),
    etc.
);
```

then, if you also need the separate arrays, you build those iterating the `$final` one, not the other way around.

complete code:

```
$final=array(
    "nagpur" => array("munish","imteyaz"),
    "kanpur" => array("ram","shyam"),
);

$cities=array();
$names=array();
foreach ($final as $city => $nnn) {
    array_push($cities,$city);
    foreach ($nnn as $nn) {
        array_push($names,$nn);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php
$cities = array("nagpur","kanpur","nagpur","delhi","kanpur");
$names = array("ankit","atul","aman","amit","manu");

$arr = array();
foreach($cities as $key=>$city) {
    $arr[$city][] = $names[$key];
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
?>
```

Let know how it goes.

Comment: thnx:) it works fine. can you please help me with one more thing.like i want to sort the names in alphabetiacal order

Comment: foreach($arr as &$values){
        sort($values);
    }

Should sort. Let know if it works. Also consider giving an upvote and accepting the answer if it does what you need.